# Need help creating a conditional statement with array

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

I wanted to create a conditional statement that would say if an element of an array is odd or even after getting the elements of the array from a line. Here's the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $numbers='23 45 34 12 9 3 56';
chomp $numbers;
my @getnum= (split(/ /, $numbers));
my $a;
if($getnum[0]>10){
  $a=$getnum[0];
  }
if($a%2==0){
  print $a, " is even";
  }
else{
print $a, " is odd";
}
```

Now the problem is I only did it for the first element. Is there a way I can do this for all elements without creating a conditional statement for each? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `for` (or `foreach`) loop.

```
for my $n (@numbers) {    # Loops over @numbers, assigning each to $n
    if ( $n % 2 == 0 ) {
        print "$n is even"
    }
}
```

Additionally, this is rather un-idiomatic

```
my $numbers='23 45 34 12 9 3 56';
chomp $numbers;
my @getnum= (split(/ /, $numbers));
```

If you have a string you wish to split on whitespace, there is a special way to do that in Perl

```
split( ' ', $string );
```

This will split on arbitrary whitespace (and will strip leading and trailing whitespace), eg.

```
my @words = split( ' ', '   one two    three  ' );
# @words is ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

But if you are just hardcoding the number in your script itself, you can bypass the `split` all-together and use the 'quote-words' syntax

```
my @numbers = qw( 23 45 34 12 9 3 56 );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It sure did! Thanks a lot!

Comment: To split hairs: (1) "_assigning each to `$n`_" in the code comment should be _aliasing each to `$n`_. If `$n` gets changed in the loop the array element does, too. (2) the `qw( ... )` returns strings, not numbers.  They'll be used as numbers in the right context but making a point of assigning `qw(..)` to `@numbers` may be a little itchy.  Why not use a list, `(12, 45, ...)`?